# How can I use other GPIO pin for I2C

Tags: i2c

I have to use i2c with raspberry pi and arduino but there's difference of voltage levels so I bought a level shifter module for i2c from http://www.devicemart.co.kr/1149321. the picture on the link, pin have to be linked directly. so I checked if there's pullup resister already on the module and I found some resisters. that resisters are not linked high voltage but some IC. I'm worry if my board can die. so I want to change I2C pin-GPIO2, GPIO3- to the the other pins. I mean I want to use GPIO 22, 27 for I2c. Is it possible? How should I do?

Comment: why do you need to use different pins?

Comment: Your question is vague. Are you planning to connect the Pi to Arduino, or connect both to some other device. As Joan states you don't need a converter, but the level shifter should be safe. It appears to have 2 MOSFET and a regulator. Only connect the power to the Pi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you need a level converter.  As long as the Arduino does not have pull-up resistors to 5V on the I2C lines it should be safe.  The Pi has hard-wired 1k8 pull-up resistors to 3V3 on GPIOs 2 and 3.

If you do want to use other GPIOs you will have to bit bang the I2C protocol.

There are probably dozens of solutions for the Raspberry Pi.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library has bit bang methods for [C](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bbI2COpen) and [Python](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_i2c_open).

Comment: A while ago [I learned](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80338/35753) that `1V8` and `3V3` (spotted [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58039/35753) as well) were equivalents to 1.8V and 3.3V, reading further in Electronics SE suggested this [notation has roots around WWII or earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28053/102305). I just noticed the `1k8 pull-up resistor` mentioned [here](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_i2c_open) as well. I'm just curious about the `8` is that equivalent to `Ω`?

Comment: [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28094/102305) mentions `4R7` which I'm guessing is `47MΩ`, but don't think `1k8` is `100MkΩ`. Thanks!

Comment: The pull-ups should be around 2000 to 10000 ohms.  Megaohms are vastly too high.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious about the notation as well, what does 1k8 mean?

Comment: "To simplify the writing of large resistor values, the abbreviations K and M are used for one thousand and one million. To keep the convention standard, R is used to represent 0. Because of problems in seeing the decimal point in some printed texts, the 3 letters: K M or R are used in place of the decimal point. Thus, a 2,700 Ohm resistor is written 2K7 and a 6.8 Ohm resistor is written 6R8." from https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Electronics/ResistorColorCodes/

Comment: Thanks again. I don't mean to keep bothering you, but I find this interesting and so I've just asked [How to read electronics notation like 3V3, 1V8 and 1k8?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2127/35753) in meta just now because it's possible others will find this interesting as well. I can transcribe your comments there as an answer in a few days if nothing happens, but please feel free to share there if like.