# GPIO outputs not changing on specific GPIO ports

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, archlinux

I'm using a Rpi B rev2 and I'm having problems changing the output of ports 2,3,4,5,6 (BCM). All the other ports work perfectly.
I searched for documentation and I see the only thing that sets these apart is that they have a default HIGH pull resistor activated. (source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)

Whatever I do (cleanup, define a DOWN pull resistor), I can't get it to change.
Can somebody clarify this behavior?

PS: I use python rpi.gpio on a Archlinux Arm distro

EDIT:
As per request; the code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT) #per example pin 4
GPIO.output(4,1)
```

The voltage on the pin 4 is a 0.8V, when I change it to 0, still the same. On all other +- 20 ports this works.

UPDATE: Due to tests I ran with hooking up a mosfet, I broke a couple of GPIO pins, Joan (see above) his tool is a great way of testing your GPIO pins. Credits to him

Comment: Please post the code you use in trying to switch the GPIOs' state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPIO 5 and GPIO 6 are not brought out to the expansion header on a PiB Rev.2.  How are you testing their value?

GPIO 2, 3, and 4 are connected to expansion header pins 3, 5, and 7 respectively.

How are you testing their value?

GPIO 2 and 3 have hard wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.   GPIO 4 has a weak internal pull-up to 3V3 enabled at power-up.

You can use http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/faq.html#Have_I_fried_my_GPIO to check your GPIO.

Comment: I'm checking some things now with wiringPI but same result. I'm testing the value with a multimeter (set to volts, black to GND pin RPIm other to pin)

Comment: It's a B+ I'm sorry, My situation is that 16 pins are perfectly working, but 4,5,6 (GPIO.BCM) are not working. I test if I fried my pi

Comment: Your program gives me an error (libpigpiod.so: no such file)

Comment: It uses pigpio which isn't installed on Arch by default.  Try wiringPi's pintest program.  It should be under the wiringPi installation directory.

Comment: I installed pigpio, put still, I'll try wiringPI

Comment: RESULT: GPIO 4 seems faulty from the pintest, but it gives errors in my spi interface also.. which is strange because that works

Comment: @Polarsbear Arch uses different library locations.  You could try copying /usr/local/lib/*pig* to /usr/lib

Comment: That fixed the starting of the deamon. Thanks for that.
RESULT: 
Write 1 to gpio 2 failed.
Pull up on gpio 2 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 3 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 4 failed.
Pull down on gpio 4 failed.
Write 1 to gpio 5 failed.
Pull up on gpio 5 failed.
Write 0 to gpio 6 failed.
Pull down on gpio 6 failed.
Pull down on gpio 7 failed.
Pull down on gpio 8 failed.

Comment: Unless you have external hardware connected to those GPIO some of your GPIO are bust.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and tool. Hooking up an other RPI now to see if that solves things.