# What is it about the redesign of the new Pi 3 B+ power supply that's discussed here?

Tags: power-supply, pi-3b+

Today's announcement at raspberrypi.org: [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ On Sale Now at $35](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-3-model-bplus-sale-now-35/) describes several improvements. In the linked [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQZxdiz2UAs) changes to the power supply are discussed between `04:30` and `05:40`, but I'm not quite sure which parts are historical review, and which are related to the most recent changes.

Could someone point out which are the main points they make here about the *new* Pi 3B+ power supply?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74550/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-what-is-it-about-the-redesign-of-the-new-pi-3-b).

Comment: In the interest of question stewardship I've cleaned up the question. The closed caption transcription was meant to be for convenience, but since they've been revised it's no longer helpful. I don't think it needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paragraph by paragraph

> So we’ve had a custom power supply from “Maxine” designed, so this is a four switch mode power supply, and so it’s “icy” controllable,
>   and it sort of Hoover’s up a lot of the shrapnel on the board, like
>   the discrete LDS that we had in the past.

A new power supply from "Maxine" which is a four switch mode power supply that is I.C. [integrated circuit] controllable. means that a lot of separate discrete Power supply components have been replaced by this one power supply chip.

> So we originally had we had this we had a separate so we had separate switches we had a dual switcher for one v8 3v3, we had a ITC
>   nose of those are fixed switches we had a controllable switch an RTC
>   controllable switcher for the core voltage, and which back in the day
>   on Pi 2 of course was the product that gave us the gave us the death
>   flash.

Discussing/listing the components replaced by the new power supply.

> And then we had an LDO for an SDRAM Braille which is now a switcher, we had two LDOs to do the SDRAM, we had an audio LDO, lots
>   of that’s been sucked into the corner, this is why it kind of looks
>   tidier, and of course that’s a because the the switcher it has better
>   static regulation accuracy, has a better load step performance on both
>   of those then turn into those those are both contributors along with
>   the changes that have happened in the in the main chip there are those
>   are things that contribute to that 200 MHz uplift you know in
>   frequency.

Further components replaced by the new power supply - and the result of all the tidying up of the circuit board and new supply being more stable and accurate allowing the team to raise the CPU clock speed by 200 MHz.

Comment: LDO is a low dropout regulator: that much I know. Most of the terms they are using are electronics engineering terms. You might be better served researching switching power supplies and looking up the meaning of the other terms and acronyms.  In other words to truly understand everything they are talking about you'll need to understand the workings of switch mode power supplies and how the supply accuracy and robustness can have an effect on the performance of the logic circuits and processors running from that supply.

Comment: @uhoh I'd be annoyed if I spent effort and time to answer the question and got that response.  Please edit your question and rephrase it to indicate what you want from an answer.

Comment: @uhoh - If you require less general answers then I'd suggest you rephrase to ask for example 'What is an LDO?' or what does 'an RTC controllable switcher for the core voltage, mean?'  Without knowledge of your current level of understanding and your actual required understanding - My answer could be viewed as sufficient. Or if you have little to no understanding of electronics then text book size answer may be sufficient or it may not.  Hence my suggestion to research and ask questions about switching power supplies.

Comment: @Charemer okay I've given it another go. Thanks for your follow-up! I have to try to remember that when I switch from one SE site to another that I look completely different on each site. How does it look now? "*It's not necessary to explain the concepts, as long as the terms are correct I can certainly read up on what they mean elsewhere if I need to*."

Comment: @uhoh that improve the question a lot - have you also tried asking about those terms on the electrical engineering stack? (electronics.stackexchange.com) You may get answers there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and patience! I think I shouldn't cross-post, but it might be a good idea to add a link to the question in the chat room there.

Comment: @Charemer, i watched the video and took liberty with updating the text from the video ... i hope you do not mind